# Use of media and data-turbolinks-track parameters in stylesheet_link_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

I'm a bit curious on what these additional parameters do when I include something like

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

in my `application.html.erb`, should I be using these parameters on all additional stylesheet links I create inside the layout? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Turbolinks has its own documentation https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#reloading-when-assets-change

> Turbolinks can track the URLs of asset elements in  from one page to the next, and automatically issue a full reload if they change. This ensures that users always have the latest versions of your application’s scripts and styles.
>
> Annotate asset elements with data-turbolinks-track="reload" and include a version identifier in your asset URLs. The identifier could be a number, a last-modified timestamp, or better, a digest of the asset’s contents

It sounds slower and sounds like it uses more bandwidth. Maybe good for a bank.

The `media` attribute of `link` HTML tag is to specify which platform and device the CSS applies to.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp

> The media attribute specifies what media/device the target resource is optimized for.
>
> This attribute is mostly used with CSS stylesheets to specify different styles for different media types.
>
> The media attribute can accept several values.

It has values like `screen`, `printer`, etc. The default is `all` so it's not very DRY to include it.